# Magento CE 1.9 Configurable quick create bug

Tags: php, magento

There appears to be a bug in Magento CE 1.9 that prevents simple products from being created for a configurable using "quick create".  The simples never appear (below the main area) for association with the configurable.

I have found problem reports from other under version 1.8.

Has anyone found a solution under 1.9?  Is it the same solution (merging of js scripts) as has been proposed for 1.8?  I haven't found any reports of that working.

Comment: I have this problem as well, did you ever find a solution?